# Month tics, how to set

Tags: gnuplot

In GnuPlot:

How to set xtics to 1st of every month?

set xtics would not work for me the as the number of seconds per month varies.

```
set xmtics
```

does not work for me because months are displayed without years and it is not shown to which year belongs a month.

Comment: I would love to see a solution to this myself; in my experience gnuplot is pretty weak at formatting x data when the data are time.

Answer (score 25):

It seems to me that gnuplot handles time surprisingly well. I assume your data in the following (or similar) format:

```
05/17/12    0.8188064359
05/18/12    0.97297057
05/21/12    0.9012782504
```

I used random numbers spread over year and a half to test this.

So first you need to tell gnuplot your x coordinate is time and what is the format it is written in:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%y"
```

From now on, gnuplot is expecting all ranges in the specified format, including the `xtics` and `xrange` commands. The only exception is the increment in `xtics` which should be in seconds.

```
set xrange ["05/01/12":"08/01/13"]
set xtics "01/01/12",2592000,"08/01/18"
```

Now you might argue, that the number of seconds in each month is different by a whole day (actually 2 days in February). However, gnuplot authors seem to think about this as well and they solved the problem to our liking. In other words, the above will ensure tics every 1st of a month. Here, I can only suggest to specify the printing format of the `xtics`

```
set format x "%d %b %Y"
```

which will result in "01 May 2012", etc. 
After this, `plot` your data. Oh, when using time on x-axis, gnuplot requires `using` in the `plot` command, so even with a trivial data file as I had, I had to use

```
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2
```

I used gnuplot version 4.6 patchlevel 0  and output to postscript terminal.
If you will have different experience with your version or terminal, let me know in the comments.

Comment: be aware that in cases where the input timefmt is different from the output/plotting time format, the xtics string is in the timefmt/xrange (input) format, not the output/plotting format.  set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d.%H%M%S"; set xrange ["2019-06-13.000000":"2019-06-14.000000"]; set xtics "2019-06-13.000000",10800,"2019-06-14.000000"; set format x "%m/%d\n%Hh"

Answer (score 4):

`set xtics` will work ok if you set the number of seconds to the average number of seconds in a month.

I worked this out by assuming 365.2425 days in the average year, dividing by 12 to find the average days per month (approximately 30.4), multiplying by hours per day then seconds per hour, i.e:

```
365.2425 / 12 * 24 * 3600 = 2629746
```

Assuming your data was formatted as year-month and value, i.e:

```
2016-01 10000
2016-02 12000
2016-03 10500
```

Then you’d need commands such as:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m"
set format x "%b/%y" # Or some other output format you prefer
set xtics "2016-01", 2629746, "2016-03"
plot "mydata.dat" using 1:2 with linespoints
```

If you want to set xtics in multiples of months then just add a multiplier in the `set xtics` line, e.g to get quarterly marks:

```
set xtics "2016-01", 3*2629746, "2016-12"
```

I found that if I assumed the number of days in a month to be 30 or 31 then some at some point in the chart, months would be missing their xtics.

### Update for Gnuplot 6

A new feature of Gnuplot 6 is setting xtics directly from time values:

```
set xtics time 1 months
```